# Synchronize object filter - outliner behavior with viewport selection

Tags: outliner

the new Blender 2.81 synchronize outliner object to viewport and vice versa feature is fantastic.  It matches up with behaviors in other 3D software like 3DS and Maya.

One question on its behavior to see if it can do this as well:

When the collections are collapsed or the object selected in the viewport is not in the outliner view, the object gets selected in the outliner but it's not brought into view in the outliner.

Is there a way to get the outliner to "jump" to the selected object - expanding and/or scrolling the outliner as needed?

Many thanks!